# Google Wallet Generic Pass Removing Card Title and Custom Font Color

Tags: .net, google-api, google-wallet

**Prerequisites**

I am working on the dotnet implementation of the Generic Pass and as per our need I don't want to display the Card Title and I also want to display a custom font color for the text on the front side of the Generic Pass. But when the card title field is set to null the card is not added in the wallet rather it displays Something went wrong message in Google Wallet. Is there a way for creating the **GenericPass** without setting the **CardTitle**.

**Expected Behavior**

- When I set the card title to null in the GenericObject the title should be set to null or empty string, and it should not be displayed when the card is added to Google Wallet via Google Pay API link.
- The card should be added successfully to the wallet regardless of the CardTitle added or not in the JWT Payload

**Current Behavior**

- The card is not added in the Google Wallet and instead the message Something went wrong appears.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- Remove the CardTitle field from the GenericObject or set the field to string.Empty or " " or null.
- Convert the model to JwtObject and create the payload.
- Create the JWT token add/concat it to the Google Pay API link.
- Use the link to add the card to the Google Wallet

**Context**

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Browser: Microsoft Edge
- Android Version: 13
- Nuget Package - Google Apis Version: 1.62.0

**Screenshots**

[image: Google Card not added to the wallet]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The `cardTitle` prop is required according to the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/wallet/reference/rest/v1/genericobject#GenericObject).